# Does manual log switch force commit?

Tags: oracle11g, database-administration

When we issue manually Alter system switch logfile, does this statement force all uncommited transactions to commit? When I issue this I see my number session raised in database and graph indicates these were commits in that period. So I was wondering if that command causes uncommited transactions to commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, open transactions are not commited by this statement. You can test this yourself:

```
create table TESTSWITCH(testid NUMBER);
insert into TESTSWITCH values(1);
select * from TESTSWITCH;
alter system switch logfile;
rollback;
select * from TESTSWITCH;
```

output:

```
table TESTSWITCH created.
1 rows inserted.
TESTID
------
     1 

system SWITCH altered.
rollback complete.
no rows selected
```